# Exclude private method execution from transaction rollback

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have a service method in my project that can be simplified like this:

```
@Transactional
public void myTransactionalMethod(){
    try {
        soSomethingAndSaveOnDB(); // private method
    }catch (Exception exception){
        saveSomethingOnDBWhenAnErrorOccurs(); // private method
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

the method is transactional and is executing some main logic that can cause an exception to be thrown. If this appens, any data saved in the DB must be restored to previous state.

But I also need to handle the thrown exception in a `catch` block and write some additional data in the DB to trace the error.

The problem with my implementation is the final `throw exception` instruction that causes the transaction rollback and prevents the creation of the data related to error tracing.

I'd like to "disable" transaction rollback for this case, in order to correcly log the error in my database.

**NOTE** I'm re-throwing the exception to propagate it to the controller and convert it in a HTTP error.

Which could be a good solution to this issue, keeping `soSomethingAndSaveOnDB()` and `saveSomethingOnDBWhenAnErrorOccurs()` methods `private`?

Comment: The need to throw the exception from the `catch` block is not clear. You have anyhow done the logging into the DB by this time.

Comment: Have you tried Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW on `saveSomethingOnDBWhenErrorOccurs`?

Comment: However, if you must throw, then throw a different exception, say `AnotherException` which can be "excepted" using `@Transactional( dontRolbackOn = AnotherException.class )`.

Comment: @SreeKumar It's right that the logging into DB it's already done, but I also need to propagate the exception to the controller and convert it in a HTTP error. So; yes I need to re-throw the exception. Thanks

Comment: @Marc as I specified in the question, saveSomethingOnDBWhenErrorOccurs is a private method and declarative transaction handling should not work on private methods.

Comment: @davioooh OK. Hope you will update if the idea of using `dontRollbackOn` worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

This seems more a workaround than a solution, but at the moment is the best approach I found following the suggestions in the comments.

I modified my method this way:

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = { ExceptionWrapper.class })
public void myTransactionalMethod(){
    try {
        soSomethingAndSaveOnDB(); // private method
    }catch (Exception exception){
        saveSomethingOnDBWhenAnErrorOccurs(); // private method
        throw new ExceptionWrpper(exception);
    }
}
```

then I defined a class like this:

```
public class ExceptionWrapper extends RuntimeException {
    private final RuntimeException wrappedThrowable;
}
```

and finally in my controller I'm catching the new exception type, this way:

```
try {
    myTransactionalMethod();
}catch(ExceptionWrapper ew){
    throw ew.getWrappedThrowable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to solve this problem that came to my mind:

1. Use [TransactionTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) with PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW scope to handle transaction programmatically in `saveSomethingOnDBWhenAnErrorOccurs`  method. This way saving error logs will be done in separate transaction.
   For example:

```
    private final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

    private void saveSomethingOnDBWhenAnErrorOccurs(){
        transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        transactionTemplate.execute(status-> repository.saveErrorLog());
    }
```

2. Use of self-injection or ApplicationContext to call logging method. However this way will require to make `saveSomethingOnDBWhenAnErrorOccurs`  method public. For example, suppose that your class called `MyService`, then:

```
    @Autowired
    private SomeRepository someRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Transactional
    public void myTransactionalMethod(){
        try {
            soSomethingAndSaveOnDB(); // private method
        }catch (Exception exception){
            LoggingData loggingData = ...
            applicationContext.getBean(MyService.class).saveSomethingOnDBWhenAnErrorOccurs(someRepository, loggingData); // private method
            throw new ExceptionWrpper(exception);
        }
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Document saveSomethingOnDBWhenAnErrorOccurs(SomeRepository someRepository, LoggingData loggingData) {
        return someRepository.save(document);
    }
```

3. Use additional abstraction layers, e.g:

```
┌────────────┐
│ Controller │
└──────┬─────┘
       │
       │
 ┌─────▼─────┐
 │ MyService │
 └─────┬─────┘
       │
       │           ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
       │ OnError   │@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)│
       └──────────►│ErrorLogging.saveSomethingOnDBWhenAnErrorOccurs     │
                   └────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```